# How to get required information based on 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How to solve this issue in SQL Server?

Table1:

```
Pid   |     Pname  | prosubcatgoryid
1     |     pen    |  100
2     |     Rin    |  101
3     |     Cap    |  100
```

Table2:

```
prosubcatgoryid      |   prosubcatgoryidDescription
          100        |   powerofwords
          101        |   wearingitem
```

Table3 :

```
Pid  | Address           |  City | datetime
1    | Homeless          |  Chen | 2014-11-13  09:32:14.000
1    | 3913 W. Strong    |  Chen | 2011-03-044 19:04:10.000 
1    | 1100 W MALLON     |  Chen | 2012-11-13  09:32:14.000
2    | 610 W GARLAND #3  |  Hyd  | 2013-11-13  09:32:14.000
```

Table1 and Table2 have a common column `prosubcatgoryid` and 
Table1 and Table3 have a common column `Pid`.

We need get `prosubcatgoryid` related information taken from table2 and `pid` related address and city information taken from table3 and we need to consider latest datetime (highest datetime value based on pid) corresponding address and city information from table3

Based on above 3 tables I want output like below

```
pid    |Pname  | prosubcatgoryid |prosubcatgoryidDescription|  Address        | City      | datetime 
1      | Pen   |  100            | powerofwords             |  Homeless       | Chen      |2014-11-13 09:32:14.000
2      | Rin   |  101            | wearingitem              |610 W GARLAND #3 | Hyd       |2013-11-13 09:32:14.000
3      | Cap   |  100            | powerofwords             |notavilable      |notavilable|1900-01-01(pass any default values)
```

I tried this query for table1 and table2

```
select 
    a.pid, a.pname, a.prosubcatgoryid, b.prosubcatgoryidDescription 
from 
    table1 
left join 
    table2 on table1.prosubcatgoryid = table2.prosubcatgoryid
```

for table3 information

```
SELECT 
    mp.id, mp.address, mp.city, mp.state, mp.datetime
FROM
    (SELECT 
         MAX(datetime) AS MaxP, id 
     FROM 
         [test].[dbo].[table3] 
     GROUP BY 
         id) MaxP 
JOIN
    [test].[dbo].[table3] MP ON MaxP.id = MP.id AND MaxP.MaxP = MP.timestamp
```

Finally I did not get any idea how to merge above 2 queries and get above result.

Please tell me  how to  write query to achieve this task  in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using outer apply and top 1, like this:

```
select 
    a.pid, a.pname, a.prosubcatgoryid, 
    b.prosubcatgoryidDescription,
    c.Address, c.City, c.datetime
from 
    table1 a
    left join table2 b 
        on a.prosubcatgoryid = b.prosubcatgoryid
    outer apply (
      select top 1 Address, City, datetime
      from table3 c
      where c.Pid = a.Pid
      order by datetime desc
    ) c
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76e61/1)

You can get the default values you want for address using isnull in the select, for example `isnull(c.datetime, '19000101')` if you don't want nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to number each row per `id` group.  With `rn = 1` you can only pick the latest row:

```
select  *
from    table1 a
left join
        table2 b 
on      a.prosubcatgoryid = b.prosubcatgoryid
left join 
        (
        select  row_number() over (
                  partition by pid
                  order by [datetime] desc) rn
        ,       *
        from    table3
        ) c
on      c.Pid = a.Pid
        and c.rn = 1 -- Only latest row
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76e61/5/0)